# Can't create BC7 texture on Xbox One

Tags: c++, uwp, directx, textures, xbox

I'm using the code to detect supported textures:

```
UInt usage=0; UINT fs; if(OK(D3D->CheckFormatSupport(ImageTI[i].format, &fs)))
      {
         if(fs&D3D11_FORMAT_SUPPORT_IA_VERTEX_BUFFER        )usage|=ImageTypeInfo::USAGE_VTX;
         if(fs&D3D11_FORMAT_SUPPORT_TEXTURE2D               )usage|=ImageTypeInfo::USAGE_IMAGE_2D;
         if(fs&D3D11_FORMAT_SUPPORT_TEXTURE3D               )usage|=ImageTypeInfo::USAGE_IMAGE_3D;
         if(fs&D3D11_FORMAT_SUPPORT_TEXTURECUBE             )usage|=ImageTypeInfo::USAGE_IMAGE_CUBE;
         if(fs&D3D11_FORMAT_SUPPORT_RENDER_TARGET           )usage|=ImageTypeInfo::USAGE_IMAGE_RT;
         if(fs&D3D11_FORMAT_SUPPORT_DEPTH_STENCIL           )usage|=ImageTypeInfo::USAGE_IMAGE_DS;
         if(fs&D3D11_FORMAT_SUPPORT_MULTISAMPLE_RENDERTARGET)usage|=ImageTypeInfo::USAGE_IMAGE_MS;
      }
      ImageTI[i]._usage=usage;
```

The problem is that `DXGI_FORMAT_BC7_UNORM`, `DXGI_FORMAT_BC7_UNORM_SRGB` and `DXGI_FORMAT_BC6H_UF16` fail for D3D11_FORMAT_SUPPORT_TEXTURE2D, meaning can't create 2d textures with these formats.

And the calls to `CreateTexture2D` also fail.
(all other formats I've tested work fine BC1 BC2 BC3 R8G8B8A8.. etc).

What's the problem? Xbox One doesn't support BC7/BC6 textures?

Edit:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/xbox-apps/system-resource-allocation

Looks like UWP is limited to Feature Level 10 which does not support these texture formats. Does this apply to only Creators or also Managed Partners?

Comment: Could you please tell me if you are using C++/CX project?

Comment: Yes this is C++ UWP DirectX 11. We are Managed Partners in the ID@Xbox program, but the Feature Level is still limited to 10.0. Does it mean we need DirectX 12?